# Closing a form view

Tags: c#, wpf

Earlier (with some much appreciated help), I was shown how to create a function that allows me to open a window (see below)

```
private void icon_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenView(typeof(viewName));
}

private void OpenView(Type newView)
{
    if(typeof(Window).IsAssignableFrom(newView)) {
        Window window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(newView);
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

I would now like to modify OpenView so that I can also tell it to close a form (and could really do with some help.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to run:

```
 OpenView(typeof(viewName), typeof(viewToClose));
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know wpf that well, but I'd guess `Window` has a `Close()` method. If correct you can use the same code but Close() the view instead of Show().

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  However, doesn't CreateInstance do just that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

[Gist with example](https://gist.github.com/Jossef/b5ed9aa76aabf5b31d02)

---

Use `Application.Current.Windows` as it stores all of the Application's windows

```
  private void OpenView(Type newView, Type closeType)
        {

            foreach (Window item in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == closeType)
                {
                    item.Close();
                }
            }

            if (typeof(Window).IsAssignableFrom(newView))
            {
                Window window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(newView);
                window.Show();
            }
        }
```